# Rails 3: simple_format not prints the text inside " "

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, html-to-text

I am using simple_format to convert text with html tags to plain text in my rails application , everything works well, But simple_format doesn't shows the text inside " "quotations

```
simple_format(post["text"])
```

This is my rails code, I have used sanitize: false also but it doesn't works.What to do?

Comment: Using `simple_format` to remove html tags sounds weird to me. That is not the purpose of that method. I would use `strip_tags` for that: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags

Comment: if i type <h1>xxx</h1> means I need bigger text with out any html tags in view. for that I am using simple_format

Comment: But `simple_format("<h1>xxx</h2>")` would return `<p><h1>xxx</h1></p>` (what is invalid html)? Can you please elaborate an example what you try to achieve?

Comment: In my rails application simple_format("<h1>xxx</h1>") returns xxx(with big font size) , it works well for all html tags except " " quotations